# Power BI - Automatic switch between tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

Actually, I do not know, whether there are any tools to do it in Power BI. Could you help me, please?
I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2), which have the same number of columns, moreover, Table 2 is filtered version of Table 1, which was created in Power BI. I have already created analytical page with different graphs for Table 1. However, I need to have the same graphs for Table 2.
Is there any list to add to this page with two options: Table 1 and Table 2? When I will need Table 2, I will choose it and all graphs will be created using this table. Is it possible?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using bookmarks. Create a button linked to the bookmark to show and hide visuals as you desire.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! I have tried. It works. But can I use different groups of bookmarks for different pages? So, I have 2 groups of bookmarks, but all these 2 groups now are on one page, however, I want one group per page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I would mark this question as solved and ask a new question with a screenshot or sample data.